# Using Python to extract employee details from Outlook is suddenly very slow

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I've been utilizing pywin32 in Python to extract names, email IDs, job titles, and other details of all members from specified Outlook distribution lists.

Initially, the code executed very quickly; although I lack an exact estimate, it could extract all pertinent details for even 100-200 or more members within 1-2 minutes.

However, after changing laptops within my organization, I've noticed a significant slowdown. The code now takes up to an hour for similar outputs. Despite searching online, I haven't found any relevant mentions of such an issue. Your guidance would be appreciated.

A sample of the code:

```py
outApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
entries = outApp.AddressLists
dist_lists = entries['All Distribution Lists']

outlookdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=['User Name','Email','Job Level','Location','Department','DL Name'])

dl_names_list = ["<insert name of distribution list here>"]

print("Distribution Lists being extracted are: ")
for i in dl_names_list:
    print(str(i))
print("----------------------------")

#########GET DL Names from list and put it in a dataframe

for i in dl_names_list:
    print("Distribution List now being extracted: ")
    print(str(i))

    #initialize widgets
    widgets = ['Remaining Time: ', pb.Percentage(), ' ', 
                pb.Bar(marker=pb.RotatingMarker()), ' ', pb.ETA()]
    #initialize timer
    timer = pb.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets,        maxval=len(dist_lists.AddressEntries.Item(str(i)).GetExchangeDistributionList().Members)).start()
    ind = 0
    m_list_1 = []
    m_list_2 = []
    m_list_3 = []
    m_list_4 = []
    m_list_5 = []
    for m in dist_lists.AddressEntries.Item(str(i)).GetExchangeDistributionList().Members:
            user=m.GetExchangeUser()
            try:
                if len(user.Name) > 0 and (user.Name.find(', ') != -1):
                        value1 = user.Name
                        m_list_1.append(value1)

                        value2 = user.PrimarySmtpAddress  
                        m_list_2.append(value2)

                        value3 = user.JobTitle 
                        m_list_3.append(value3)
                        
                        value4 = user.OfficeLocation
                        m_list_4.append(value4)
                        
                        value5 = user.Department
                        m_list_5.append(value5)
                timer.update(ind)
                ind = ind + 1
             except:
                continue
    timer.finish()
    print("---------------------------------------------------")

    df_m = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(
    {'User Name': m_list_1,
     'Email': m_list_2,
     'Job Level': m_list_3,
     'Location': m_list_4,
     'Department': m_list_5
    }))
    df_m["DL Name"] = str(dist_lists.AddressEntries.Item(str(i)).GetExchangeDistributionList().Name)
    outlookdf = pd.concat([outlookdf,df_m])

outlookdf = outlookdf.drop_duplicates()
outlookdf = outlookdf.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: does `dl_names_list` get large? because at first glance, `outlookdf = pd.concat([outlookdf,df_m])` is a well-known anti-pattern. Don't incrementally build a dataframe using `pd.concat`, instead, make a list of dataframes using `list.append`, then `pd.concat` the list at the end.

Comment: Hi, the code is taking time in the functions .GetExchangeUser(), .Name, .PrimarySMTPAddress, .JobTitle etc. This is because the progressbar shows very slow progress. I have also tried variations of the code without appending values to list or creating a dataframe; just to test the speed of obtaining the above data but it still shows same very slow speed. Also, I have tried the same thing with just one distro list. The code is taking 4-5 seconds to extract details of each member, which becomes a problem because we have around 90 distros with an average of 200-300 members each.

Comment: `within 1-2 minutes.` that's *very* slow. You're using COM Automation to call another process's API (Outlook), and that's always slower than calling a library or an Exchange web service that returns all data at once. The objects used are managed by Outlook so member calls are additional cross-process calls. The code is retrieving the same distribution list multiple times with `dist_lists.AddressEntries.Item(str(i)).GetExchangeDistributionList()` and then trying to use its `Members` property twice and `Name` once.

Comment: Where are the distribution lists stored? In the current user's Outlook? An Exchange Server? Outlook Online? If you use COM Automation to call a remote server the delays will be a lot worse

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe an exchange server

Comment: I have tested the code on 3 other systems belonging to my team mates. They have slightly older laptops but the model and processor are the same in 2 cases. The code is running extremely fast on all their systems (~1 minute for 900 member distro list as opposed to ~40 minutes in mine). I also tested with both PyCharm and Jupyter and with Python 3.9 (similar to their systems) and 3.11 on mine. Code is slow in my system in all cases. IT dept says nothing is different with Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; which was to simply download the Address Book in Outlook so that it would use the Offline Address Book (updated once every 48 hours). Previously Python was connecting to Address Book (Global Address List) in external server which is why the code was taking such a long time. Hope this is helpful to anyone facing similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do in OOM alone - with the `AddressEntries` collection, you are forced to access one entry and one property at a time. `AddressEntries` object does expose the `RawTable` property  (returns `IMAPITable` MAPI object), but it cannot be used in Python, you'd need C++ or Delphi. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use the [Redemption.MAPITable](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm) object - it allows to retrieve all values in a single call.

In VBS:

```vb
set addrEntries = Application.Session.AddressLists("Offline Global Address List").AddressEntries.Item("Everybody").Members
set Table = CreateObject("Redemption.MAPITable")
Table.Item = addrEntries
'0x39FE001F is PR_SMTP_ADDRESSS, need to specify it as a DASL name for ExecSQL
set Recordset = Table.ExecSQL("SELECT Name, ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F"", JobTitle, OfficeLocation, Department from List")
while not Recordset.EOF
    Debug.Print(Recordset.Fields(0).Value & " - " & Recordset.Fields(1).Value & " - " & Recordset.Fields(2).Value & " - " & Recordset.Fields(3).Value & " - " & Recordset.Fields(4).Value)
    Recordset.MoveNext
wend
```